# What's difference between using metrics 'acc' and tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

When calling a model's compile method, we can pass in metrics.

Why is `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` different than `'acc'`?

For example, the following 2 calls give different results:

`model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])`

vs.

`model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=['acc'])`

I noticed that when using the callback `on_epoch_end`, the keys for `logs` dict changes for the 2 cases above.  Using `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()` will result in `logs` with a key `accuracy`, but it's always 0.  However, using 'acc' will result in a `logs` with a key `acc` that has values as expected.

Comment: please, specify TF version

Comment: `tf.__version__` is 1.14.0

Comment: For people now using tf 2.2+, according to the [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), "In TensorFlow 2.0 keras models are more consistent about handling metric names. Now when you pass a string in the list of metrics, that exact string is used as the metric's name....This differs from previous versions where passing `metrics=["accuracy"]` would result in `dict_keys(['loss', 'acc'])` " See also [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy)

Answer (score 6):

Took some digging, but I believe the difference is:

`acc` used `def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, threshold=0.5)` in `metrics.py` under the hood

while

`tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` used `class Accuracy(MeanMetricWrapper)` in `metrics.py`.

I came to this conclusion by testing & inspecting the source code for [tensorflow's keras metrics.py file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py)

Comment: I'll just add that as of tf v2.2 in [training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fabcd8f89cd5975331994049705e15cb75f32e0c/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L463) the docs say "When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one of `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy`, `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy`, `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy` based on the loss function used and the model output shape. We do a similar conversion for the strings 'crossentropy' and 'ce' as well." See also [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27217)